# How to handle STL container with elements of classes containing large arrays of data

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, stl, large-data

I am looking for a way to put large arrays of data (stored inside a class holding basic functionality like checks on the data, size etc) into any STL container, like a vector or a queue (FIFO queue is best since I have a producer and a consumer).

The problem is that I have to implement the copy constructor and.. well.. I don't want to make a deep copy (since it takes too much time, so I stick to a shallow copy), but then again I have the problem of not knowing when to delete the array of data in the destructor (since I call the destructor twice and only have the data once, plus, the first call to the destructor likely comes from inserting/moving the element in the container, so I still need the array-data at that point).

I thought about using smart pointers like std::shared_ptr for the data array, but from what I have read they don't call delete [] but rather delete - which is a shame since I have an ordinary array [].

Right now I have a solution that by hand calls a "DeleteArray" function on the class before removing it from the container. It works great but.. it is not nice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost has a `shared_array` class that is like `shared_ptr` but will use `delete[]`, or you can add a custom deleter to `shared_ptr` that will make it call `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an array, use a `std::vector` instead.  Then point at that with a smart pointer.

Comment: That adds an extra layer of indirection to accesses, though: you would have a bunch of `vector`s in the heap, each of which points to a separate array of data in a different location in the heap.

Comment: @Jeremiah: True, but no more so than any other use of a container class.

Comment: @Oli: When using a `vector<shared_ptr<vector<...> > >`, you would have a `vector` of pointers to individual `vector` objects (each of which is only a few words of memory), and each of those objects would point to a separate data array.  Using something like `shared_array` would remove one of those levels of indirection.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Maybe we're talking at cross purposes.  Rather than `int *pArray` as a class member (as the OP is considering), I'm advocating `shared_ptr<vector<int> > spVec`.  I'm not sure where the second layer of `vector` has come from in your comment.

Comment: @Oli: That's what I meant too -- the question said that there would be an STL container of large arrays, so something like `vector<int*>` that you suggested replacing by a `vector<shared_ptr<vector<int> > >`.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Jeremiah: To be honest, it could be either of us misunderstanding.  My understanding of the original question is that the OP's invariant is `vector<SomeClass>`.  Each `SomeClass` currently contains an `int *`, hence the copy-constructor/destructor quandary.  So I was suggesting replacing that member with a smart-pointer to a vector.

Comment: @Oli: That's about what I had in mind too, except that I didn't see that he was using a class containing the array rather than a raw array in the outer container.  My understanding is that you suggested changing the `int*` in his class to `shared_ptr<vector<int> >`, while I suggested `shared_array<int>` instead.

Comment: @Jeremiah: On reflection, the `shared_array` is probably the cleaner approach!

Answer (score 1):

Even better solution would be to put `shared_ptr`s to your large objects into the containers and avoid expensive copies all together.

#### Edit 0:

Another option, of course, is to make the objects themselves lightweight and copyable with `shared_array`. as Jeremiah suggests.

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation for down-voting.

Comment: The question already mentioned using `shared_ptr`, along with the problems with doing that the obvious way.

Comment: The question mentions using `shared_ptr` for *member arrays* within the large objects.

Comment: The large objects mentioned in the question are the data arrays, though.

Comment: "stored inside a class holding basic functionality like checks on the data, size etc", huh?

Comment: @Nikolai: I didn't see that detail, but it seems like his classes are lightweight other than the data arrays.  Your suggestion would remove the need to copy them, though.  I apparently can't remove my vote now, however, unless you edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `shared_ptr` equivalent for arrays, at least in the Boost libraries. It's called `shared_array`, and it behaves exactly as you would expect. Check out the specification at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm?sess=8940ad57baa307d68cb2e7fd2939d2db.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement simple reference counting in your copy constructor. You can decrement the reference with each delete.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your insightful answers!

This reminds me why the last time I had this problem I handcoded a queue without copying myself. I can't say it took me much longer than figuring out how to do the nice, clean version. :)

So.. what I did is:

Solution a)
Like described in the original post, I created a function that had to be called explicitly before removing a class from the vector. Not nice but it worked great and I didn't have to mess with anything else, just remember to call it.

Solution b)
I put the array in yet another class and used a smartpointer (shared_ptr) to that class. Worked really nice. I had to use shared_ptr s as elements of the vector too. (I didn't think of this at first.)

Solution c)
Using shared_ptr to hold an array. Pretty bad idea as it turns out, since it calls delete instead of delete [] you need to provide your custom deleter and somehow some other (syntax) problems emerged so it took me something like 2h+ to do that solution.

It looks something like that in the header file:

```
 template< typename T >
  struct
array_deleter
  {
      void
    operator ()( T const * p)
      { delete[] p; }
  };

class MemoryStressChunk
{
private:
    int chunkSizeInValues;
    std::shared_ptr< __int64 > data;
};
```

and in the code file:

```
data.reset(
    new __int64[chunkSizeInValues], 
    array_deleter< __int64 >() );
```

and to use it I have to get it out again:

```
__int64 *d = data.get();
```

Next time I might strongly consider using the boost versions. I didn't have boost on my machine so that is why it was not an option for me.

I take it
Solution d) would be to use a vector of classes containing a shared_ptr s to a vector (instead of an array). After all the fun I had with c) I did not do that on top. :)

If someone wants to have a look at the code, you can get it here http://andreas-reiff.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Tool-MemTester.zip . Beware there probably is a memleak in version a) (use shared_ptr for the class as in version b) ).

Thx for all your help again!